# C# search in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview, datagrid

I'd like to get a search method in my Datagrid. I fill my datagrid by databinding from a dataset.

```
      <Grid Name="Grid_Kind" Background="#FFFFAF00">
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridKind" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,21,0,166">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=KindID}" Header="ID" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=VNaam}" Header="Voornaam" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ANaam}" Header="Achternaam" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Straat}" Header="Straat" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Huisnummer}" Header="Huisnummer" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Plaats}" Header="Plaats" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Postcode}" Header="Postcode" Width="Auto" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="695" Loaded="txtSearch_Loaded" Text="Zoeken" GotFocus="txtSearch_GotFocus" />
```

Thats the Xaml i got so far

and this is the C# part

```
    dsKind KindDataSet = new dsKind();
    dsKindTableAdapters.KindTableAdapter KindTableAdapter = new dsKindTableAdapters.KindTableAdapter();

    private void FillData()
    {
        KindTableAdapter.Fill(KindDataSet.Kind);
        this.DataContext = KindDataSet.Kind.DefaultView;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillData();
    }
```

Comment: What are you searching for?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: a search method for a datagridview (sorry if it wasn't clear)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code as a quick search option, where tsbSearch is a ToolStripButton and tsTxtSearch is a ToolStripTextBox.

Using a BindingSource for the DataGridView, it automatically searches by Description (NMS_Description), LongDescription (LongDesc) and Location (LOCATION) upon pressing Enter or Return while in the Text Box.

```
private void tsbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tstxtSearch.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            this.nEAR_MISSBindingSource.Filter = "NMS_Description LIKE '*" + tstxtSearch.Text + "*' OR LongDesc LIKE '*" + tstxtSearch.Text + "*' OR LOCATION LIKE '*" + tstxtSearch.Text + "*'";
        }
        else
        {
            this.nEAR_MISSBindingSource.Filter = "";
        }
    }

    private void tstxtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            tsbSearch_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reaction but where did you get nEAR_MISSBindingSource from?